# Determinant of Skew-Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry

Let $M \subset M_n(\mathbb C)$ be the set of $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrices.

1) If $n$ is odd their determinant is equal to $0$.

2) If $n$ is even their determinant is a polynomial (in several variables) which is NOT irreducible as an element of $\mathbb C[x_1, \dots,x_r]$.

Partial Solution:

1) $A=-^TA \implies \det(A)=(-1)^n\det(^TA) \implies \det(A)=0$.

2) When n=2 $$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & x_1  \\
-x_1 & 0  \end{array} \right) $$

we get $p(x_1)=x_1^2$.

If $n=4$

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b & c\\
-a & 0 & d & e\\
-b & -d & 0 & f\\
-c & -e & -f & 0\end{array} \right) $$

we get $p(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(be)^2 - (af+cd)^2=(be+af+cd)(be-af-cd)$.

I tried to use $2\times 2$ block matrices or to compute $\det$ along a raw with no success in the general case.

Comment: Your computation of the determinant of the 4x4 matrix is incorrect. It should be $(af-be+dc)^2$. If you compute the 6x6 determinant (perhaps with the aid of a computer algebra system), you should see a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is given by the Pfaffian. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian).

Concretely, let $A$ be your matrix, and consider the induced skew bilinear form $B$ on $V=k^r$. One can show there is a basis $\mathscr B$ of $V$ such that $B$ has the form $S=\mathrm{diag}(s,\ldots,s,0,\ldots,0)$ where $s=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$. This means that there is some invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$PBP^t = S$$

and then $\det B$ is a square. This is an inductive argument, muchlike that of Gram-Schmidt orthongalization.

To do this generically, consider the field $F=\mathbb Q(x_{ij}:i<j)$ and the corresponding generic skew matrix $X$. By the above $\det X$ is a square in $F$, and one can write $\det X = (f/g)^2$ with $(f,g)=1$ over $\mathbb Z$. Now one obtains

$$g^2 \det X=f^2$$
and because $\det X\in \mathbb Z[x_{ij}]$ and this ring is a UFD, one gets $g$ is a unit, that is, $g=\pm 1$.