# Without expanding the determinant.

Tags: determinant

> In the below determinant, without expanding the determinant we have to prove that the determinant is zero.

[image]

I know how to solve it by expanding, but without that I have no idea.

Comment: Look at point $1)$ here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068032/determinant-of-skew-symmetric-matrices

Comment: Any time there exists symmetry in the matrix, you can guarantee that the determinant is 0. To see this, perform a cofactor expansion and see for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** The determinant of a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ of odd order is always $0$. Check this by $A=-A^t$ and $\det A^t=\det A$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix has a null space containing $\begin{pmatrix}a\\ c\\b\end{pmatrix}$ at least. As long as one of $a,b,c$ are nonzero then the nullspace is nontrivial,  but if they're all $0$ then the matrix is the $0$ matrix to begin with. Either way, the determinant is $0$ because it has a nontrivial nullspace.